# Word meaning "far greater than required or necessary"

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word that means 'far more than necessary. Like if I needed 5 apples, but got 25, my gain or success would be described as...X. I think I may have heard 'overt' used like this in the past, but not sure. Not exactly like 'major increase', and basically the opposite of 'marginal'. Thank you guys!

Comment: Who is looking? And what is it that you like? And which male members of this community are you thanking, and are you discriminating against the female ones?

Answer (score 1):

The word I immediately thought of, which sounds similar to *overt*, is [**overkill**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overkill#h2):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **2** : an excess of something (such as a quantity or an action) beyond what is required or suitable for a particular purpose
>     // publicity *overkill*
>     // an *overkill* in weaponry

In describing the situation in the question, you might way the following:

> Buying 25 apples for a pie is *overkill*.

It has a more literal sense, but is often used in this figurative sense too.

Answer (score 1):

OED

> **excessive** (*adjective*)

> **2. Of qualities, states, actions, magnitudes, etc.**

> **b. Exceeding what is right, proportionate, or desirable; immoderate, inordinate, extravagant.**

> 1875   B. Jowett in tr. Plato Dialogues (ed. 2) III. 681   *A single night of excessive rain..left the rock of the Acropolis bare.*

Merriam Webster

> **excessive** (*adjective*): exceeding what is usual, proper, necessary, or normal

Collins:

> **excessive** (*adjective*)

> 1 (adjective)  in the sense of immoderate: The length of the prison sentence was excessive considering the nature of the crime.

Answer (score 1):

Those apples are *surplus* or *superfluous*.

> **[Surplus (adjective)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/surplus):** More than what is needed or used; excess. [**Lexico**]

> **[Superfluous (adjective)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/superfluous):** Unnecessary, especially through being more than enough. [**Lexico**]

Answer (score 0):

glut (n.)
1530s, "a gulp, a swallowing," from glut (v.). Meaning "condition of being full or sated" is 1570s; mercantile sense "superabundance, oversupply of a commodity on the market" first recorded 1590s.

Answer (score 0):

superabundance. noun. A condition of going or being beyond what is needed, desired, or appropriate.